# will deleting an appid on developer portal have an effect on my app in app store..?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-id

I have an appid in my apple developer account which I would like to delete and recreate using a different APP ID prefix. Will this have an effect of my application which is already in the app store, will it leave it unusable..?

And if I delete and create a new one with the same value and then deploy this on the app store and a user updates then will this be downloaded as a new app or will it update the old app..? I am pretty sure that it will update the old app but just want to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html

Basically I wanted to change the prefix of my app id from something to my TEAM ID. It seems that I have to get in touch with apple guys to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. It will not reflected. It will still usable & users can download.
2. Not able to understand your words "create a new one with the same value" ? :)